# Azure dev fabric crashes with SocketException when using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, crash, azure, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to run ASP.NET MVC 2 web site under the Windows Azure Dev Fabric using the DotNetOpenAuth OpenID authentication.

**Azure Dev fabric itself repeatedly crashes** (dfloadbalancer.exe), when I authenticate.

Are there any workarounds for the issue that allow to use Azure Dev fabric and DotNetOpenAuth?

MSDN seems to have some [old discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/6681bd01-f9c7-456b-90d6-5b4151d8b99b/?prof=required) on the same issue which has been abandoned.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
  Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=10054
  NativeErrorCode=10054
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown how)
       at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.LoadBalancer.ConnectionInfo.Release()
       at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.LoadBalancer.ServerConnector.Stop()
       at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.LoadBalancer.PacketForwarder.ProcessReceive(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
       at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
  InnerException:
```

Latest log messages before crashing are:

```
[WaWebHost.exe] Redirecting to http://www.myopenid.com/server?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxx.myopenid.com%2F&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxx.myopenid.com%2F&openid.assoc_handle=xxxxxxx&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fuser%2FAuthenticate%3FReturnUrl%3D%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fxxxxxxxx.myopenid.com%252F&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
[fabric] Role state Unresponsive
```

Comment: All I can say is "it works for me".  Can you add a relevant code snippet of how you do the redirect?

Comment: I didn't do the redirect. That comes from the DotNetOpenAuth logger. Implementation matches to the simple ASP.NET MVC app that is distributed along with your library.
It looks like the problem is in the load balancer that somehow chokes on this redirect **after** it happens.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this problem when using this following statement:

```
return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

I corrected this by changing the line to:

```
string location = request.RedirectingResponse.Headers["Location"];
return Redirect(location);
```

For reasons unknown to me, this got around the error and allowed me to get back to business without making any special changes to my development environment.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the information! I've posted a query on Windows Azure Forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/49a05dd2-bd15-4be4-840b-77eed44cc6a9

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, and it's still happening years later.

Comment: `AsActionResult()` is the best code because it won't randomly fail when the redirect is formatted as a scripted form post instead of a 301 redirect with the Location header. I suspect the crashing may be due to missing bindingRedirects in the web.config file. Make sure that you have appropriate redirects for MVC from 1.0 to the version you're actually using.